# Java tool for automatically generating documentation for SOAP-based APIs?

Tags: java, api, documentation-generator, soap

Is there any Java tool that, given an JavaEE SOAP API, the tool will automatically scan the package containing the endpoints of the service. The tool should also provide access to a route (something like `localhost:port/api-docs`) and when accessing that route, the list with all endpoints will be displayed and for each endpoint related details will be displayed. Like what arguments it takes, what it returns, etc.

Comment: I believe you are looking for a tool rather than a library? What will launch the generation? Someone, or another program?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul The generation is launched by another guy. Basically, what I am looking for is a Swagger for SOAP,  but I am not allowed to mention software names here...

Comment: If the generation is launched by a person, then you indeed need a tool rather than a library. There are a hundred ways of using Swagger, we can not read into your mind to find out what is your personal usage of it.